# Cannot make xargs construct to work

Tags: xargs

I have a strange problem with **xargs**.
I have an **xargs** construct  which does not work, even though 
when I echo the command, it works perfectly.
My one liner is the following:

```
 exiftool -p exifprintformat  -if '$Subject =~/DATA/i' -q  *.pdf |grep pdf |sed 's/ //g'|xargs|xargs -0 -I % pdftk % cat output binder1.pdf
```

and the output

> Error: Unable to find file. Error: Failed to open PDF file: 
>      20170105170516234.pdf 20170105173126944.pdf 20170105173209758.pdf 20170621163418079.pdf

- The `exiftool` selects all the pdf that contain the word DATA in the subject tag,
- The `-p exifprintformat` instructs `exiftool` to print only the file name,
- The `grep` selects only the lines with pdf,
- The `sed` removes whitespaces,
- The first `xarg` makes all the lines into one string and the second constructs the bind command)
  when I run

> exiftool -p exifprintformat  -if '$Subject =~/DATA/i' -q  *.pdf |grep
>   pdf |sed 's/ //g'|xargs|xargs -I{} echo pdftk {} cat output
>   binder1.pdf

I get

> pdftk 20170105170516234.pdf 20170105173126944.pdf
>   20170105173209758.pdf 20170621163418079.pdf cat output binder1.pdf

which works perfectly.

Obviously, I am doing something wrong...But what?

Comment: `grep` expects line endings (probably present) and `darfst -0` expects NUL bytes (probably missing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong, and unnecessary complexity:-

1. The double `xargs` call means that the second sees a single line of input, so `{}` is substituted just once with a single string comprising all the matching file names, but `echo` does not show this difference in the output (compare `echo a b` with `echo "a b"`).
2. The `-0` argument means that `xargs` needs a null (`'\0'`) character between input arguments, and there are none; this also forces the input to be treated as a single parameter.
3. By outputting only the file name when the condition matches, you get one file name per line, which can be piped directly to `xargs` without the need for `grep` or `sed`.
4. Unfortunately, `xargs -I` forces one command per line of input, and there is no option to add trailing parameters, but there is a simple work-round: add the trailing parameters to the input stream.

This is a simplified command with the trailing parameters added (I tested with a different `-if` condition, not having any PDFs which match):-

```
{ exiftool -p '${FileName}' -if '$Subject =~/DATA/i' -q *.pdf; \
  echo -e "cat\noutput\nbinder1.pdf"; } | xargs -d'\n' pdftk
```

The `xargs -d'\n'` option makes the command work when the file names have embedded blanks.

Comment: thnx for the elaborate answer, and for pinpointing all the mistakes.. Have some doubts for remark no 3, as exiftool also prints two lines other than file names that have to be thrown out..

Comment: @GrigorisL. - All I can say is that the command works fine for me, and the `exiftool` command I quoted produces only a single line with the file name. For the record my `exiftool` revision is 10.10 and I am running Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @ΑFH You are quite right after all. When the -p $ FileName is invoked from the bash, it prints out only file names. When it is invoked from a parameter file, as i did it originally, the output is more perplexed.

Comment: OK, but I put `${FileName}` as the only line in a file (no comments, headers, etc) and this worked equally well. I used the in-line string for testing and, since my final format was so simple, there seemed no point in putting it in a separate file. By the way, `{}` are optional in this case: the simpler `$FileName` is equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The man page for xargs says:

> -I replace-str
>
> ```
>   Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with
>   names read from standard input.   Also, unquoted blanks do not
>   terminate input items; instead the separator is the newline
>   character.  Implies -x and -L 1.
> ```

In other words, you're ending up with a single argument called "`20170105170516234.pdf 20170105173126944.pdf 20170105173209758.pdf 20170621163418079.pdf`"

I suggest ditching xargs altogether and re-ordering your command something like this:

```
pdftk $(exiftool -p exifprintformat -if '$Subject =~/DATA/i' -q *.pdf |grep pdf |sed 's/ //g'| tr '\n' ' ') cat output binder1.pdf
```

This all assumes you don't have spaces in your filenames (safe assumption since you were removing all spaces with sed anyway).

Comment: thnx! As a newbie, this subtle difference (argument vs arguments) had to be pinpointed to me... Newbie aha moment.. My previous understanding was that xargs called shell -or something- to execute command... Obviously, not so...